# How to install a Vulkan extension?

Tags: macos, vulkan

I was implementing an algorithm using Vulkan. There seems to be one extension missing in my Vulkan sdk. Where can I download this extension and how can I install it?

I have known the exact extension I need but I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: If you know the extension, why don't you tell?

Comment: lol, sorry. The extension is  VK_KHR_portability_enumeration.

Comment: Likely part of MoltenVK driver or Apple specific Loader.

Answer (score 0):

Vulkan extensions are provided by the driver of your GPU, you cannot install them by yourself.
If the extension you looking for is more recent than the driver of your GPU, you can still try to update it.
Otherwise, it's mean your extension is not supported by your hardware and there is nothing you can do about.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I installed the Vulkan SDK, there was a warning saying: "NOTICE: As of the 1.3.216 SDK release,  the Vulkan Portability Enumeration extension is being enforced by the Vulkan loader.  Failure to 'opt in' for non-conformant Vulkan implementations will cause applications to fail to find the MoltenVK ICD.  See the macOS release notes for more information. " I am no expert in Vulkan. Could you please tell me what this means?

Comment: @JohnnyWang97 MoltenVK is not a conformant Vulkan implementation, therefore it is not visible unless you tell Vulkan it should make it visible.

Comment: @krOoze could you tell me how to make it visible?

Comment: @JohnnyWang97 I don't have Apple, so my advice would be urealiable. It should be part of MoltenVK and the associated Loader, however you installed those and assuming you did all the manual said properly.